# Curl and Div equal to zero -

Tags: calculus

What does it mean When $Curl \ F = 0$ or $Div\ F = 0$ ?

F  is a vector field

I am new in vector calculus;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl measures how much the field is rotating.  If you enclose a region with (defined) curl of 0 everywhere, the line integral around that curve will be zero (Greens' Thm.)

Divergence measures how much the field is expanding.  If you enclose a region with a (defined) divergence of 0 everywhere, the flux integral around the curve will be zero (normal form of Greens' Thm).

Comment: I feel "rotating effect of field" is better than "field is rotating".